# How to search strictly by city state in geocode python

Tags: python, geopy, nominatim, geocoder

I'm using geopy Nominatim to get latitude longitude for a given city state, but the problem is, it searches for everything in an address and not just the city state.

My implementation is something like this:

```
        geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='clear-sky-finder')
        location = geolocator.geocode(f"{city}, {state}")

        if not location: 
            raise APIException("City not found", 404)
        lat = location.latitude
        long = location.longitude
```

If I give it something like Chandler, Arizona, it works, but I want it to fail if I enter something like "Chan, Arizona" but it still pulls results because theres some restaurant with the word Chan in it somewhere in Mesa, Arizona.

I tried something like this:

```
        location = geolocator.reverse(f"{lat},{long}")
        location_city = location.raw['address']['city']
        
        if location_city != city: 
            raise APIException("City not found", 404)
```

But this way it misses some cities such as "Waddell" because it counts it as part of a different city.

Is there any way I can get it to be city specific?

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that worked for me.
You require to set "addressdetails=True" for geocode.
Then you can get more detail about the address.
I got this for "Paris".

address
{'suburb': 'Paris', 'city_district': 'Paris', '**city**': 'Paris', 'ISO3166-2-lvl6': 'FR-75', 'state': 'Île-de-France', 'ISO3166-2-lvl4': 'FR-IDF', 'region': 'France métropolitaine', 'country': 'France', 'country_code': 'fr'}

If the name of the city in location1.raw["address"]["city"] is matched with your input, then it is the name of a city.

Note: I suggest also checking the value of "town" for your problem. The structure of the address is different for different inputs.
Sometimes "geopy" provides a "town" or "municipality" key instead of a city for the input data.
Check the output of location1.raw["address"] for several of your input data.

---

```
import geopy
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="MyApp")
location1=geolocator.geocode('Paris',addressdetails=True)


for key in location1.raw.keys():
    print(key)
    print(location1.raw[key])
    print("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1uQy.png)